# How to output the text with the format I want

Tags: python, text

I have meet a problem that I want to delete the duplicates or use other signs to replace them except the last time by Python . For example:

Before: `aaaabbbbcccc||ddddddd||eee||fff`

After: `aaaabbbbccccdddddddeee||fff`  OR
`aaaabbbbcccc,ddddddd,eee||fff`

Answer (score 1):

There are **many** ways to achieve this. The ground principle is to separate the last item and handle it individually.

Here are a few possibilities that do not require imports:

###### using a list as intermediate

```
s = 'aaaabbbbcccc||ddddddd||eee||fff'

l = s.split('||')
','.join(l[:-1])+'||'+l[-1]
```

###### functional way

```
'||'.join(map(lambda x: ','.join(x.split('||')), s.rsplit('||', 1)))
```

###### limited replacements (require 2 reads of the string)

```
s.replace('||', ',', s.count('||')-1)
```

output: `'aaaabbbbcccc,ddddddd,eee||fff'`

Answer (score 1):

Using regex:

```py
import re
x = "aaaabbbbcccc||ddddddd||eee||fff"
x = re.sub(r"\|\|(?=[^\|]*\|\|)", ",", x)
print(x)
```

Result:

```
aaaabbbbcccc,ddddddd,eee||fff
```

Use empty string to get the first example:

```
x = re.sub(r"\|\|(?=[^\|]*\|\|)", "", x)
>>>
aaaabbbbccccdddddddeee||fff
```